# PHP replace HTML tags

Tags: php, html, tags

I have a text which can contain HTML tags. I want to be able to
view it in plain text without html tags being parsed by browser exactly the way
HTML code viewers do.

for example:
replacing `<div>` with `<span><</span><span>d</span><span>i</span><span></span>v<span>></span>`.

the text may also contain utf-8 characters like Arabic or Farsi.
and also all tags must be replaced.

for example:

```
there is no html tags in this line.

the following line is in farsi:
این یک متن نمونه است به زبان فارسی

<div>
    <label>
        This is a sample text.
    </label>
</div>
```

the last 4 tags must be replaced in the above code and also the farsi characters must be still readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

```
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```